# Issue propagating images from a fetched JSON API call

Tags: reactjs

I created this code to render different cards with the images sourced from an API call:

```
import React from "react";
import './IGPostCard.style.scss'

export const PostCard = ({timelinePhotos}) => (
        <div className='postContainer'>
            
            {
                timelinePhotos.filter((item, idx) => idx < 12)
                    .map(({id, display_url}) => (
                        <img className='cardTemplate' key={id} src={display_url}/>
                    ))
            }
        </div>
    )
```

A link to the full project can be found here: https://github.com/GhostCrawl3r/Instagram-Website-Addon

From a console.log this is the fetched API data shown in the development console:
[image]

I'm not very good at using the map function, so it's likely I made a mistake in it's implementation.
Theoretically, I should be able to cycle through this array and pull the display_url from each component and render it.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `timelinePhotos` prop is the array that you've included in the screenshot, the correct way to iterate through those items with `Array.map` would be the following:

```
const PostCard = ({ timelinePhotos }) => (
  <div className="postContainer">
    {timelinePhotos
      .filter((item, idx) => idx < 12)
      .map(({ node }) => (
        <img 
          className="cardTemplate" 
          key={node.id} 
          src={node.display_url} 
        />
      ))
    }
  </div>
);
```

This is because each element in the array is an object with a `node` property that holds the properties & values you'd like to display.

If you'd like to destruct even further, you could do something like the following:

```js
const data = Array.from({ length: 20 }).map((_, idx) => ({
  node: {
    id: idx + 1,
    display_url: `https://example.com/post/${idx + 1}`
  }
}));

console.log("example", data[0]);

const temp = data
  .filter((item, idx) => idx < 12)

  // destruct property of an object
  .map(({ node: { id, display_url } }) => {
    console.log(id, display_url);
    return { id, display_url };
  });
  
console.log("result", temp[0]);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so, so much! - This worked perfectly and I learned a lot from this. I'm so incredibly grateful, thank you so much! :)

Comment: @NickMorgan great! Glad I was able to help.